# How do you go about making random outcomes for notes in Friday Night Funkin' Psych engine?

Tags: haxeflixel

Please help. I am trying to figure out how to make random outcomes for custom notes in Friday Night Funkin' Psych Engine. So far, this is what I got. Can someone please help me? I would appreciate it.
EDIT: The trace(random) showed me the outcome. The result was it picking a number between 1 & 4 while not activating the if triggers. The desired outcome of it was for it to pick a number between 1 & 4, with that number setting off one of the if triggers, triggering that event.

```
                        
                        case 'Luck Note':
                        var random:Int = 0;
                        random = FlxG.random.int(1, 4);
                        trace(random);
                        if(random == 1){
                            health = 2;
                        } else if(random == 2){
                            health = 0.1;
                        } else if(random == 3){
                            health = 1;
                        } else if(random == 4){
                            health = 0;
                        }
```

Comment: What was the result of `trace(random)`. What's your desired outcome? What happens currently? Please EDIT your question, and include pertinent details.

Comment: I changed it to include those details

Answer (score 0):

Is this being checked every frame? A.k.a make sure that the switch case is inside update() (or in a function that is inside update()) so it can check for the values every frame.